# HTML5 apps available in Android Marketplace?

Tags: android, html

Are there any app built with html5 feature (such as canvas, video playback...) available in Android marketplace?

I'm looking for html5 web apps wrapped as a native android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.phonegap.com/apps

search the page for android

Comment: Thanks Brian. I downloaded a few but I can't really tell if they are using any html5 specific feature.